# URL data accessed as form data in POST webservice

Tags: java, web-services, post, jax-rs

My webservice interface is something like

```
@Consumes("application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
@POST
@Path("/testCall/{id}")
Object testCall(@PathParam("id") String myId, @FormParam("formId") String formId, @Context HttpServletRequest request);
```

Now I call webservice as POST with following URL from REST client

```
https://myTest.com/1.0/testCall/12345?formId=007
```

it works fine. I fail to understand when I have mentioned `formId` to be a form param why does it accept data from URL param?

Comment: Look like a bug maybe caused by the fact that HttpServletRequest doesn't differentiate between query params and form params, when you call getParameter. Not sure. I was able to reproduce it in Jersey 2.

Comment: do you also have a `formId` in the POST data?

Comment: @wero No. There is nothing in POST data.

Comment: I don't know what JAX-RS impl you are using, but with Jersey 2.x, if you look [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.glassfish.jersey.containers/jersey-container-servlet-core/2.0-rc1/org/glassfish/jersey/servlet/WebComponent.java#WebComponent.filterFormParameters%28javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest%2Corg.glassfish.jersey.server.ContainerRequest%29), you can see that Jersey builds the form map by call `HttpServletRequest.getParameterValues`. This doesn't differentiate between query params and form params. They are all inside whatever structure is holding the params.

Comment: If you are not using Jersey, I would imagine other implementations have the same problem, as the container reads the stream so it can't be read again, and all the params (query and form) are put into the `HttpServletRequest` param holder

Comment: @peeskillet actually Jersey gets it right. JAX-RS implementations do their own parsing of the request body, and only fall back to the ServletRequest if a filter has called getParameter() before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Javadoc of `@FormParam` is clear about the source of the parameter:

> Binds the value(s) of a form parameter contained within a request
>   entity body to a resource method parameter.

There seem to be three possibilities for the observed behaviour:

1. The request content also contains the parameter (not in your case)
2. The implementation has a bug
3. The request content was already consumed by a filter

The [JAX-RS spec](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/jaxrs-2_0-fr-eval-spec/index.html), chapter 10.1. explains the third possibility:

> Servlet filters may trigger consumption of a request body by accessing
>   request parameters. In a servlet container the @FormParam annotation
>   and the standard entity provider for application/x-www-form-urlencoded MUST obtain their values from the servlet request
>   parameters if the request body has already been consumed. Servlet APIs
>   do not differentiate between parameters in the URI and body of a
>   request so URI-based query parameters may be included in the entity
>   parameter.

Comment: Thanks @were do you have link to this documentation?

Comment: @AniketThakur added a link to the spec. Did case 3) happen in your app?

Comment: Thanks. Yes I have multiple filters configured.